# Override linear gradient CSS attribute

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have the following class definition:

```
height: 99px;
width: 961px;
padding-top: 40px;
font-size: 15px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background: no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,h64GFj4fhffGFHJJ74fhf);
```

However, the site's javascript (which I can't influence) is adding a `linear-gradient` property to the background:

```
height: 99px;
width: 961px;
padding-top: 40px;
font-size: 15px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 153, 204, 0.701961) 0%, rgba(0, 153, 204, 0.701961) 100%) no-repeat, url(data:image/png;base64,h64GFj4fhffGFHJJ74fhf);
```

Now, without javascript, only through CSS, how can I override property, as in: nullify its effect?

I googled it and what I found is adding `filter: none !important;` to my original class definition, but that doesn't work.
Other suggestions include adding `background-image: none`, but I want to keep my background image.

Comment: Can't you use a more specific selector and override it?

Comment: How is the JS changing the background? Is it actively changing the written CSS or adding inline styling? This might be a case where `!important` might be the best option. We really need a link or more information.

Comment: Could you show us some HTML and the javascript that is adding the gradient?  That will give us a better picture of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to add these two lines in the css sheet:

```
background: none !important;
background: no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,h64GFj4fhffGFHJJ74fhf) !important;
```

Ugly but I think it may work