# Cannot override CSS gradient

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a website with Hugo and one of the sections requires a flex-box, this is a simple example of what I'm doing:

```
<div class="flex-container">   
    <div class="photography">
        <h1>Photography</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="art">
        <h1>3D Art</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.photography { 
    background: none !important;
    background: no-repeat url("https://thedivtagguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/InstagramSize.jpg") !important; 
    min-height: 200px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.photography h1 {
    color:white;
}

.art { 
    background:blue;
    min-height: 200px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

However, there's this really weird linear gradient which is being applied somewhere in the theme's CSS. I can't seem to be able to override it in any way I know how, is there a way to fix this?

I've uploaded a repo of the entire code [here](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/gallery), if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried undoing a gradient using `!important` ?

Comment: Where would I do that? I don't know where this is coming from. What I did do, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481018/override-linear-gradient-css-attribute) was `background: none !important; background: no-repeat url("https://thedivtagguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/InstagramSize.jpg") !important;`

Comment: You can see where style is coming from in dev tools of browser. If it doesn't respond to `important!` - style is defined inline, or by higher selector specificity. You can try to change class names of elements, and see what happens, or you can try to strengthen specificity by adding `.flex-container .photography` instead of just `.photography` in your CSS.

Comment: IOOIIIO is right, adding "!important" could be not efficient if the original style has already an "!important" flag. So the best solution is to find the incriminated style with the debugger of your browser and add a more specific CSS selector (like adding the current parent class or even better an ID because the weight of ID is greater than class).
Here is an article about using Chrome devtool : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css

Comment: Thank you @IOOIIIO, this makes a lot of sense. Let me check if this will work as soon as I am back on the laptop.

Comment: @Foxlab Thank you for the link! I shall try it out as soon as I can.

Comment: As a sidenote, a page should only have one `h1`.